# How do I load a website using a python file?

Tags: python

I would like to load a website using a python code, about every 30 seconds or so. I'm wondering how it's possible for me to load a website/reload a website using a python file. I'm not worried about the content of the website, I would just like it to be loaded, as it is to log out of a software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to do this, there is a really simple way. Webbrowser is part of the standard library so there is no need to install any additional modules.

```
from webbrowser import open
open('https://youtube.com')
```